# Always missing 'System.Data.Entity.Design'

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, visual-studio-2013

Recently while working on a webp project within Visual Studio 2013, I updated a website that was using Entity Framework Database First, and wanted/needed to update to EF 6.  Upon doing so I also needed to update the EF EDMX designer in order to support EF 6. The upgrade went perfectly fine within the web app I was working on.

I later opened a previous web project, one which does not make any use of EF, and was greeted with the application error message "Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.Entity.Design'."  I thought it was odd, that I was getting this error in a project that has 0 references or utilization of EF in anyway. Thinking it was something weird in VS I closed it and attempted to reopen the project and run it, but again the same error. So I then added System.Data.Entity.Design to the references list and I STILL couldn't run it, so I changed the properties to "Copy Local: True" and it finally worked.

I have been encountering this issue in all web projects I open and create, unless I already fixed the issue with the Copy local change. I figured that something with the update must not have occurred correctly and therefore not installed the EF DLLs to the GAC so I tried using gacutil to make the install using the command gacutil.exe /i System.Data.Entity.Design.dll but was presented with error message below.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to resolve this issue? While it's not project breaking, it is rather frustrating whenever opening or creating projects to add an unnecessary DLL to the project simply to get it to run and debug.

[image: Application Error Message]
[image: Gacutil error]